# How to create a dynamic cell for a table view using nib files

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, core-data

I'm learnings how to work with nibs, and a newbie in general.

I have a table view and another view where I create objects to populate this table view with. I'm using core data too.

My table view does not get populated...This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];

    cell.textLabel.text = target.body;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

And this is my nib:

[image]

Would love to get help here...thanks!!

Comment: Your code looks fine, but there's not enough info to troubleshoot. Did you implement numberOfRowsInSection? Is cellForRowAtIndexPath even getting called?

Answer (score 1):

you can use autolayout I think it's the easiest way !!

when you use nib you must register your nib

example: `tableView.registerNib (UINib (nibName: StoreCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: StoreCell)`

and you must have UILabel number of lines set to 0

this test project for you https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5cwzok1327vv1e/tableTest.zip?dl=0[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5cwzok1327vv1e/tableTest.zip?dl=0)